# iOS 10.3.1 enterprise application download error : Cannot connect to “Web server address” only for one wifi network

Tags: enterprise, failed-installation, ios10.3

Our website has a link to download the enterprise application build and it was working fine before. In iOS10.3.1 this link stops working only in one of our Wifi NetWork "ABC Net". It's giving an error message: Cannot connect to “Web server address”
Other Wifi Networks and 4G able to download successfully using same website and same link.

Scenarios

1. Using Wifi "ABC net" can't download giving an error message "Cannot
   connect to “Web server address”
2. Using Wifi "DEF net" can download without problem
3. Using 4G can download without problem
4. Using 4G or Wifi "DEF net" click on the link and cancel the download. connect back to Wifi "ABC net"  with the same link now able to download.
5. Using 4G or Wifi "DEF net" click on the link and cancel the download. connect back to Wifi "ABC net"  with the same link now able to download But if I cancel it again and go to iPad AppStore app and clear the cache then come back and try to download it fails again.

What I want to know is when first time trying to download enterprise app from a weblink after user tap on Open in "iTunes" Does AppStore app cache anything from the connected wifi network?

Please Help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Same problem here. Do u find any solution ?

Comment: @sivakrishna This is a certificate issue. Make sure your wifi network has a proper certificate up to date

Comment: But Im able to download the same app in other iphone using same Wifi network

Comment: You may try to reset the appstore cache in your device. Open Appstore app Tap 10 times on first tab will start refresh and clear cache.

Comment: Tried it still same thing unable to install at this time

Comment: here is my console report 
<SBUserNotificationAlert: 0x9560d10; title: Unable to Download App; source: appstored; pid: 154> due to reason: (
    "Restricted because there's no presenter that can handle this alert item at this time."
)

Answer (score 0):

The same .ipa can successfully installed on iOS10.2 ,including iPad and iPhone device.But when it comes to iOS10.3, it failed, I have test this in two iPhone device.
......
Long time past,I found a solution.There is a little change when install certificate profile on ios10.3 and later. see here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477 .